# Convert ASCII in hex to string in python

Tags: python

I use windows 7 and python 2.7. I want to convert sting：`'['3732', '3130', '2039', '6638', '6420', '3765', '6632']'` , which stands for the ASCII in hex of '7210 9f8d 7ef2'(including blank space)
to str: `'7210 9f8d 7ef2'`

(The ASCII of 7 in hex is 37, 2 is 32, blank space is 20)

I have tried:

```
f = ['3732', '3130', '2039', '6638', '6420', '3765', '6632']
 g = []
 for i in f:

   g.append(i.decode("hex"))

print str(g).replace(', ', ' ').replace('\'', '')
```

but the result is `[72 10  9 f8 d  7e f2]`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, that's not a valid string

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use `''.join()`. So, rather than using:

```
print str(g).replace(', ', ' ').replace('\'', '')
```

replace this:

```
print ''.join(g)
```

Or you can replace all your code with:

```
f = ['3732', '3130', '2039', '6638', '6420', '3765', '6632']
print ''.join([i.decode("hex") for i in f])
```

The output would be:

> '7210 9f8d 7ef2'